# Winning avalanche with all pebbles on avalanche mode?

Tags: mancala

Is it possible to win avalanche mode with all 48 pebbles able to only use your side? IE the game pidgeon version?

If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this article](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2017/05/22/how-to-win-all-marbles-in-mancala-on-your-first-move-with-matlab/), you can capture all 48 turn 1 in avalanche mode if an avalanche triggers on both sides.  If you can only place on your side of the board, you can still capture 42 stones on turn 1, which guarantees a victory but not a sweep.